# JNLP request permission twice for the jar files

Tags: java, security, sockets, jar, jnlp

I am currently running my JNLP, and in the Java Console, I see that for some jar file, it requests permission twice. Since my jar have a trusted certificate, it would cause the certificate checking request sending twice as well. The followings are what I see in the Java Console

```
security: JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission requested for: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar  
ruleset: finding Deployment Rule Set for   
        title: Xpert.ivy Rich Internet Application  
        location: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/pro/System/Administration/1419CBE3AAB8C361.jws.jnlp;jsessionid=EF178D8454450E00CC95762C3869DD3A  
        main location: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar  
        main version: null  
        isArtifact: true  
ruleset: no rule applies, returning Default Rule  
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar  
security: Istrusted: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/pro/System/Administration/1419CBE3AAB8C361.jws.jnlp;jsessionid=EF178D8454450E00CC95762C3869DD3A false  
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar  
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API  
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: FCB73268A88D254A997683F535ACA1E3F05E8538B82FFE5F0E3F3E71E9EF81B6  
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 235C96A2E2DA557B904E90F3A0CAA57EABB4BDB5F401969DA8C282F60839568F  
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: A45EDE3BBBF09C8AE15C72EFC07268D693A21C996FD51E67CA079460FD6D8873  
security: The OCSP support is enabled  
security: The CRL support is enabled  
security: Skipping revocation check, not publisher cert  
network: Connecting http://ocsp.quovadisglobal.com/ with proxy=DIRECT  
security: OCSP Response: GOOD  
security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL  
security: Grant socket perm for http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar : java.security.Permissions@64424952 (  
 ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.72.72" "connect,accept,resolve")  
)  
security: JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission requested for: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar  
ruleset: finding Deployment Rule Set for   
        title: Xpert.ivy Rich Internet Application  
        location: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/pro/System/Administration/1419CBE3AAB8C361.jws.jnlp;jsessionid=EF178D8454450E00CC95762C3869DD3A  
        main location: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar  
        main version: null  
        isArtifact: true  
ruleset: no rule applies, returning Default Rule  
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar  
security: Istrusted: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/pro/System/Administration/1419CBE3AAB8C361.jws.jnlp;jsessionid=EF178D8454450E00CC95762C3869DD3A false  
Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar  
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API  
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: FCB73268A88D254A997683F535ACA1E3F05E8538B82FFE5F0E3F3E71E9EF81B6  
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 235C96A2E2DA557B904E90F3A0CAA57EABB4BDB5F401969DA8C282F60839568F  
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: A45EDE3BBBF09C8AE15C72EFC07268D693A21C996FD51E67CA079460FD6D8873  
security: The OCSP support is enabled  
security: The CRL support is enabled  
security: Skipping revocation check, not publisher cert  
network: Connecting http://ocsp.quovadisglobal.com/ with proxy=DIRECT  
security: OCSP Response: GOOD  
security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL
```

You can see that the JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission request for the jar file twice (from line 26-45 they are the same to line 1-21).

My own quest is the one that cause the problem is this line

```
security: Grant socket perm for http://192.168.72.72:8061/ivy/rdlib/syntheticaAddons-1.226.jar : java.security.Permissions@64424952 (  
 ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.72.72" "connect,accept,resolve")  
)
```

For some other jar files, the above lines (for Grant socket perm) do not appear, so this file is just checked once.

In this case, I am now updating to JRE 7 update 40, and in the Java Control Panel, I enable the "Mixed code (sandboxed vs. trusted) security verification"

Then I try to disable the "Mixed code (sandboxed vs. trusted) security verification", then:

- The jar files that are checked 1 time (in the above situation) are
  not checked permission any more.
- The jar files that are checked twice (in the above situation) are still checked 1 time (and the "security: Grant socket perm..." still appear)

What could be the problem here ? Is this a security bug or is there something wrong in my jars or JNLP ?

Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is running under java security manager, each type of action needs to have explicit permission.

When you enable certificate mode for trusted jar, the jar access permission is passed through JVM in mixed mode, but still the socket access needs explicit permission.

http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html lists all type of permissions and their risk from security manager's perspective.

The possible way to connect host is:
 accept
 connect
 listen
 resolve

By default you have *connect,accept,resolve* to host 192.168.72.72.